# uitableview cell in has a lateral separator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to make a very simple indexed tableView in Swift 3.
I managed to add the index to the view, but as soon as I added the sections headers, every cell showed a strange separator line on the right side ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UIYx.png))

I have no idea where it could come from and it doesn't appear in other indexed tableview tutorials I saw online.

This is the code for the TableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var tableData : [String] = []
    var indexOfNumbers : [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let numbers = "100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500"
        tableData = numbers.components(separatedBy: " ")

        let indexes = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15"
        indexOfNumbers = indexes.components(separatedBy: " ")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return indexOfNumbers.count }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 1 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.section]

        print(indexPath.section, indexPath.row, separator : " ")

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int
    {
        let temp = indexOfNumbers as NSArray
        return temp.index(of: title)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        return "Section \(section)"
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]?
    {
        return indexOfNumbers
    }
}
```

What could I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to comment out or remove the following delegate function.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int
    {
        let temp = indexOfNumbers as NSArray
        return temp.index(of: title)
    }
```